# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL) Invalid argument - ./ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed ruby then update gem, here trying to install rails using following command
gem install rails. But Installing is breaking with following error:-

Installing ri documentation for actionpack-4.1.4
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - ./ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/:

Operating system is :- Windows 7.

Here I am getting blank

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but simply retrying the operation helped.

Comment: It pains me to upvote a "try it again" answer, but I literally got the same error and trying it again DID in fact work like a charm.

Comment: Showed "**successfully installed rails 4.2.0**" when retried but new prob arises **Parsing documentation for rails-4.2.0
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/akshaysurve.jpg, skipping** is showing with similar **unable to convert** statements. Is this neglectable?