# How to resolve error while executing gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please help me to resolve the following error.when i am executing the command

```
gem install rails
```

on command prompt i got the following errors.

Errors:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - ./ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/:
```

MY os is-windows-7 64 bit
I am using ruby version 1.9.3 and rail-4.0.

Comment: could you provide the full log including run command?

Comment: or just try `gem install rails --no-ri -no-rdoc`

Answer (score 0):

If you refer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/tQaUYraXnGI you can find:

> Actually the "error" is an exception, triggered by Ruby documentation
>   generator (RDoc) that is captured by RubyGems.
>
> If you take a closer look to the output screenshot you attached, you
>   will see above all the "Installing ri documentation" messages a
>   success message "29 gems installed"
>
> The issue with the documentation generator may be solved by updating
>   RDoc (gem update rdoc).

Also a SO answer suggests just *"trying it again"* might work like a charm.

Here: [ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL) Invalid argument - ./ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364221/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeinval-invalid-argument-actiondispat)