# Why am I unable to install Rails on Windows command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After running the Rails installer on my Windows 7 laptop, the command line with directory set to C:\Sites appears. I try to run the command below

```
gem install rails
```

But I get the error below:

Error executing gem ...

(Errno::EMSGSIZE) A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself. - recvfrom(2)

Here is screen shot:
[image: Error on rails install]

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea, one suggestion I located: https://github.com/juthilo/run-jekyll-on-windows/issues/40. My thinking it's not a rails issue per se, but more one of environment..

Comment: I've downgraded to Ruby 2,0,0. Now as I run the rails installer in the command line, part of the install process seemed to have run, and then I get Error: While executing gem ... (Errni:TINVAL) Invalid argument - ./ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scooping/:

Comment: No idea, I gave up on Windows, and am very happy using Mint - that's why I just commented rather than tried to anwer. To your next issue, again, no idea, BUT.. maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364221/error-while-executing-gem-errnoeinval-invalid-argument-actiondispat/25713874#25713874

Comment: If you are serious about rails development you really want to abandon windows and go with a 'nix system. I'd recommend a spin-off of ubuntu like kubuntu or lubuntu. 16.04 is the new LTS. You could run with a dual boot system keeping your windows install. But you're just going to have headache after headache with windows. The other thing you will notice is just how much slower things are. Save yourself the hassle I say

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 and I had exactly the same error:

[image: rails install error win10]

The same buffer issue is being addressed here: https://github.com/juthilo/run-jekyll-on-windows/issues/40 as commented out by Tim, however, the gem being installed is jekyll.

I thought I'd install it on my end too and interestingly it worked:

[image: gem install jekyll]

So I thought I'd try to do an update. The holy grail (at least for me) is:

```
gem update --system
```

[image: gem update system]

and then do an install on your rails gem:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-doc
```

[image]

worked like a charm! I had **--version 4.0.0** appended as I needed a rather older version of the rails. I'm expanding my skill set and I'm just getting started with ROR.

Hope it helps!